# Copy camera position/rotation to another scene

Tags: camera, scene

I want to copy a camera from one scene to another, keeping the perspective. In the scene I copy it from the camera is animated to follow a path, in the second scene it should stay still.

How can I copy (not link) the camera, so that in the scene I copy it to, it does not follow the path in the second scene?

Comment: Are you copying the camera position in frame 1?

Comment: Yes, I copy it from the first frame. Why does that matter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple ways you could do this:

## Copy/Paste

1. Copy the camera (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>) in the first scene
2. Paste it in the new scene (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>)
3. Assuming you are using a *Follow Path* constraint, *Apply Visual Transform* (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>) with the pasted camera active.
4. Delete the *Follow Path* constraint.

## Link/Unlink

1. Link the camera to the second scene (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>*> Objects to scene*)
2. Switch to the second scene and unlink the camera (<kbd>U</kbd>*> Object &
   Data*)
3. *Apply Visual Transform* and delete the *Follow Path* constraint.

Comment: Thank you, I tried the Link/Unlink, but as soon as I apply the visual transform the camera moves to another location/rotation. I have the camera set up to follow a path and to track an empty.

Comment: The copy/paste solution did work for me.

Comment: @Georg That is expected, it should jump back to where it was once you delete the constraint. If you didn't use the constraint and instead parented the camera to the path via the *Follow Path* option, do `Alt P` *> Clear and keep transformation* instead of *Apply Visual Transform*

Comment: `Alt P >` _Clear and keep transformation_ did the trick, thank you!